# Page Control Width issue

Tags: iphone, ios, uipagecontrol

We have page control width 100 but then also it is going in weird manner

[image]

Please help how to handle its width

Edit:

```
[pageControl setFrame:CGRectMake(100,258,100,10)];
```

This is how i have set frame.I have cross checked no other place i am changing frame.
Number of pages are dynamic
Whole setting i have done by coding NOT interface builder

Comment: are you sure it's width is 100 and not it's numberOfPages?

Comment: Sakshi pls explain in detail ...

Comment: I think it no. of pages is 100.

Comment: I have added more explanation in my question.Please refer to it..Thanks

Answer (score 2):

try this line in `viewDidLoad:` method and also write this code after assign pages to this control ......

```
 yourPageControl.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
```

and also for PageControl align center use bellow line...

```
yourPageControl.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin;
```

you can also do this setting from Interface Builder

**UPDATE:**

```
//use this code instead of your for init UIPageControl
pageControl = [[UIPageControl alloc] init];
pageControl.frame = CGRectMake(100,258,100,10);
pageControl.numberOfPages = 2;//set here pages which you want..
pageControl.currentPage = 0;
pageControl.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingNone;
[self.view addSubview:pageControl];
```

Comment: hey @Sakshi exactly whats the pro??

Comment: page control is going out view bounds though i have set frame

Comment: @Sakshi use my above UPdated code for add UIPageControl in your view

Comment: But i can't make static number of pages.Like you have given 2.They are  coming from server

Comment: ok its not issue but when you get that number or data from server after add my above code and test it now and tell me what you got ok :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27919/discussion-between-paras-joshi-and-sakshi)

Comment: @Sakshi till its not work perfect then post your code otherwise click on above comment...

Answer (score 2):

I am too late but still,
Try the following code, It will restrict the dots into the bounds of page control

```
pageControl = [[UIPageControl alloc] init];
pageControl.frame = CGRectMake(100,258,100,10);
pageControl.numberOfPages = 100;
pageControl.currentPage = 0;
pageControl.clipsToBounds = YES;
[self.view addSubview:pageControl];
```

Here you can see the dots coming inside the bounds.

Answer (score 1):

Just need to set the property **"clipsToBounds"** to true.

Answer (score 0):

**How I fix:**
*double the width from height*

```
pageControl.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 2, y: 1)


 pageControl.clipsToBounds = true
```